# attempt to index field 'text' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am receiving the following error in my wow client during addon development/

```
83x FrameXML\OptionsFrameTemplates.lua:157: attempt to index field 
'text' (a nil value)
FrameXML\OptionsFrameTemplates.lua:157: in function <FrameXML\OptionsFrameTemplates.lua:156>

Locals:
self = ShiftDropDown_Button {
 0 = <userdata>
 toggle = ShiftDropDown_ButtonToggle {
 }
}
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = nil
(*temporary) = "attempt to index field 'text' (a nil value)"
```

I am calling it in the XML file with this

```
        <Button name="ShiftDropDown_Button" inherits="InterfaceOptionsListButtonTemplate" text="Select Target">
            <Size>
                <AbsDimension x="150" y="10" />
            </Size>
            <Anchors>
                <Anchor point="TOPLEFT">
                    <Offset x="189" y="-115" />
                </Anchor>
            </Anchors>
            <Scripts>
                <OnLoad>
                    ShiftDropDown_Button_OnLoad(self)
                </OnLoad>
                <OnClick>
                    ShiftDropDownFrame:Show()
                </OnClick>
            </Scripts>
```

and the function in the Lua is here

```
function ShiftDropDown_Button_OnLoad(self)
    self:RegisterEvent('ADDON_LOADED')
    self:SetScript('OnEvent', function(self, event, ...)
        if event == 'ADDON_LOADED' and ... == 'TauntMasterReborn' then
            TauntMasterRebornDB = TauntMasterRebornDB or {}
            for option, value in pairs(TauntM_defaults) do
                if not TauntMasterRebornDB[option] then TauntMasterRebornDB[option] = value end
            end
            self:SetText(TauntMasterRebornDBChar.SHIFTTARGET1)
        end
    end)
end
```

Can anyone shed some light on why it is throwing this error? I have searched through lots of examples and cannot find a way to debug this or solve myself.

Comment: Please show the line `OptionsFrameTemplates.lua:157` (that line must have `text` in it)

Answer (score 5):

Your button inherits from `InterfaceOptionsListButtonTemplate` which inherits initially from `OptionsListButtonTemplate`.

This template has a button text:

```
<ButtonText name="$parentText" justifyH="LEFT" wordwrap="false"/>
```

Here is the code, where the error occures:

```
function OptionsListButton_OnEnter (self)
  if (self.text:IsTruncated()) then
    GameTooltip:SetOwner(self, "ANCHOR_RIGHT");
    GameTooltip:SetText(self:GetText(), NORMAL_FONT_COLOR[1], NORMAL_FONT_COLOR[2], NORMAL_FONT_COLOR[3], 1, true);
  end
end
```

It tries to use the property value of the button text - in this case `self` - by using `self.text`. The `text` parentKey isn't assigned in the xml file but in the `OnLoad`
function, which was overwritten by yours.

To fix your template, you have to expand your `ShiftDropDown_Button_OnLoad` function:

```
function ShiftDropDown_Button_OnLoad(self)
    self.text = _G[self:GetName() .. "Text"];
    self.highlight = self:GetHighlightTexture();

    self:RegisterEvent('ADDON_LOADED')
    self:SetScript('OnEvent', function(self, event, ...)
        if event == 'ADDON_LOADED' and ... == 'TauntMasterReborn' then
            TauntMasterRebornDB = TauntMasterRebornDB or {}
            for option, value in pairs(TauntM_defaults) do
                if not TauntMasterRebornDB[option] then TauntMasterRebornDB[option] = value end
            end
            self:SetText(TauntMasterRebornDBChar.SHIFTTARGET1)
        end
    end)
end
```